# Google Ads API using Service Account throws excemption "Missing Refresh token"

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

I'm moving this Python code to .NET 6:

```
''' Run this for google Ads'''
%pip install protobuf==3.15.6
%pip install google-ads
%pip install google-auth

import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,timezone
import json

''' Imports for google ads'''
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

credentials = {
    "developer_token": "xxxxxxxx-xxxxx",
    "use_proto_plus":True,
    "json_key_file_path": "/path_to_creds_file/credentials.json",
    "impersonated_email": "username@test.com",
    "login_customer_id": '0123456789'
}

client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)
ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService") 

''' Query to get dimension table at campaign level '''
Query = '''
            SELECT 
                campaign.id,
                campaign.name,
                campaign.bidding_strategy_type,
                campaign.start_date,
                campaign.target_roas.target_roas,
                campaign.advertising_channel_type,
                campaign.advertising_channel_sub_type
            FROM campaign
            ORDER BY
                campaign.id
            PARAMETERS
                omit_unselected_resource_names=true
        '''
ga_data_pull_request = client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest")
ga_data_pull_request.customer_id =  "0123456789"  
ga_data_pull_request.query = Query
 
response = ga_service.search_stream(request=ga_data_pull_request)
```

Without exposing private information the credentials.json file is in the following format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234",
  "private_key_id": "123abc...xyz987",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabc123...xyz987==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234@xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "01234567890123456789",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234%40xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I've followed these Google Docs:

- https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs
- https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts

I have also managed to piece other solutions by following Linda Lawson:

- https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples

But I am having problems making this work in .NET 6 - here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    originalCode(false);

    GoogleAdsConfig config = new GoogleAdsConfig();
    config.UseGrpcCore = true;
    GoogleAdsClient client = new GoogleAdsClient(config);

    // Get the GoogleAdsService.
    GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsService = client.GetService(
        Services.V14.GoogleAdsService);

    // Create a query that will retrieve all campaigns.
    var campaignDimQuery = @"SELECT campaign.id,
                                    campaign.name,
                                    campaign.bidding_strategy_type,
                                    campaign.start_date,
                                    campaign.target_roas.target_roas,
                                    campaign.advertising_channel_type
                                FROM campaign
                                WHERE campaign.status = 'ENABLED'
                                ORDER BY campaign.id
                            PARAMETERS omit_unselected_resource_names=true";

    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(5000);
    CallSettings callSettings = CallSettings.FromCancellationToken(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    var request = new SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest
    {
        CustomerId = "0123456789",
        Query = campaignDimQuery,
    };

    // throws exception
    googleAdsService.SearchStream(request,
        delegate (SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse resp)
        {
            foreach (GoogleAdsRow googleAdsRow in resp.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(googleAdsRow);
            }
        });
}
```

According to this [YouTube video from Google Ads Developers](https://youtu.be/P9cC2Q_tMqY) I only need to set the following values in the app.config:

```
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="xxx-xxxxxxxxx-1234"/>
    <add key="NetworkCode" value="0123456789"/>

    <add key="OAuth2Mode" value="SERVICE_ACCOUNT" />
    <add key="OAuth2SecretsJsonPath" value="credentials.json" />
```

However, the error I get is this:

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occurred in metadata credentials plugin. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_request", Description:"Missing required parameter: refresh_token", Uri:""   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.FromHttpResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, IClock clock, ILogger logger)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock, ILogger logger)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.FetchTokenAsync(String userId, TokenRequest request, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.FetchTokenAsync(String userId, TokenRequest request, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.RefreshTokenAsync(String userId, String refreshToken, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Grpc.Auth.GoogleAuthInterceptors.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<FromCredential>b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.